# How to select column first cell value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want the column first cell value, how to select it help me.is there first function exists in mysql.

Comment: what you tried so far? Describe your question what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Rows in database tables are mostly not ordered. To get an order in your result, you use a `ORDER BY` clause. To get only the first row of this ordered set, you can use the `LIMIT` clause. So your query would be:

```
SELECT
    column1
FROM
    yourtable
ORDER BY
    whatever_column_is_appropriate
LIMIT 1
```

The syntax of [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) may be a bit overwhelming at a first glance:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
      [PARTITION partition_list]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    ...
```

It's a good idea to work through some database tutorials to get a grip on SQL.

Comment: Do not give answer such question this will encourage to user to post silly question and make lazy to googling his question.

Comment: @Sadikhasan The problem of people new to databases, as I see it, is mostly a wrong idea of tables. They think of them rather as spreadsheets.

Comment: You have to give documentation link which help to learn mysql.